# Density function after a transformation.

Tags: statistics

Assume $Y$ has the density function $q(y) = 3y^2$ when $y \in (0,1)$, overwhise zero. Let $Z = -log(Y)$. Then;
$$P(Z \le z) = P(-log(Y) \le z) = 1 - P(Y \le e^{-z}) = 1 - F_Y (e^{-z})$$
Then I calculate $F_Y$ by integrating, and I get $F_Y(x) = x^3$, which gives $F_Z(x) = 1 - e^{-z3}$, when I differentiate to find out the density.

Is above correct, or did I make a mistake some place?

Also, what my question is more precisely about: Can I always do above ,or are there some restrictions? Where is my new density function defined?

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a random variable with cdf $F_X(x)$, then any function of $X$, say $g(X)$, is also a random variable. Since $Y = g(X)$ is a function of $X$, we can describe the probabilistic behavior of $Y$ in terms of that of $X$. That is, for any set $A$, 
$$\Bbb P(Y \in A) = \Bbb P(g(X) \in A),$$
showing that the distribution of $Y$ depends on the function $FX$ and $g$.
Formally, if we write $y = g(x)$, the function $g(x)$ defines a mapping from the original sample space of $X$, $\mathcal X$, to a new sample space, $\mathcal Y$, the sample space of the random variable $Y$. That is,
$$ g : \mathcal{X}\to \mathcal{Y}.$$

We associate with $g$ an inverse mapping, denoted by $g^{-1}$, which is a mapping from subsets of $\mathcal Y$ to subsets of $\mathcal X$, and is dened by
$$ g^{-1}(A) = \{x\in \mathcal X : g(x) \in A \}.$$
The probability distribution of $Y$ can be defined as follows. For any set $A \subset\mathcal Y$,
$$
\Bbb P(Y \subset A) = \Bbb P(g(X) \subset A) = \Bbb P(\{x\in \mathcal X : g(x) \in A \}) = \Bbb P(X \in g^{-1}(A)).
$$
If $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables, the cdf of $Y = g(X)$ is
$$F_Y (y) = \Bbb P(Y \le y) = \Bbb P(g(X) \le y).$$

If $g$ is monotone, then $g^{-1}$ is single-valued; that is, $g^{-1}(y) = x$ if and only if $y = g(x)$. If $g$ is increasing, this implies that
$$ \{x\in \mathcal X : g(x) \le y \} = \{x\in \mathcal X : x \le g^{-1}(y) \}$$
If g is decreasing, this implies that
$$ \{x\in \mathcal X : g(x) \le y \} = \{x\in \mathcal X : x > g^{-1}(y) \}$$

Finally, let $X$ have cdf $F_X(x)$, let $Y = g(X)$, and let $ g : \mathcal{X}\to \mathcal{Y}$.

1. If $g$ is an increasing function on $\mathcal X$, $F_Y (y) = F_X(g^{-1}(y))$ for $y \in \mathcal Y$.
2. If $g$ is a decreasing function on $\mathcal X$ and $X$ is a continuous random variable, $F_Y (y) = 1 -F_X(g^{-1}(y))$ for $y \in\mathcal Y$.